# Android use HorizontalScrollView for landscape and ScrollView for portrait

Tags: android

I want to use different layout for landscape and portrait screen. In portrait I want to use HorizontalScrollView which scrolls horizontally. In landscape I want to use ScrollView to scroll vertically.

They work well except that when I turn my device direction from portrait to landscape, it crashes complaining HorizontalScrollView can not be casted to ScrollView.

Should it reload the layout instead of casting the components? The stack is all in android code and not my code so I don't know what to do with it. Please help, Thanks!

This is the layout file in res/layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv_tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d0d0d0"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#b0b0b0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tools_draw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tools_draw"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/tools_new" />
```

And this is the layout in res/layout-land:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv_tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#d0d0d0"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#b0b0b0"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

The crash happens when I rotate the mobile phone, stack trace is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.HorizontalScrollView$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2604)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2670)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4370)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.HorizontalScrollView$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onRestoreInstanceState(ScrollView.java:1834)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14953)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3249)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3255)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3255)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3255)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3255)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14931)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1036)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:991)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Comment: Please share your code and stack trace so that we can help.

Comment: I'm confused why you are trying to use horizontal scroll view for vertical scrolling and why can't you use just scrollview for that vertical scrolling?

Comment: Sorry typo in description. I mean in portrait screen I want a HorizontalScrollView to scroll horizontally, in landscape screen I want a ScrollView to scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what you may think, [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView) does not inherit from [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView).

They both have SavedState inner classes, but they are different.

When you change orientation from portrait to landscape or vise versa, this causes your scroll view with id hsv_tools to save its instance state using its SavedState.

Then, when the Activity/Fragment is recreated and your layout is inflated and the state is restored, and since you are using the same id for both the ScrollView and the HoriztonalScrollView, the SavedState placed in the Bundle will be for the scroll view as it was before the orientation change.

This is what leads to the ClassCastException.

I would suggest, since you have an entirely different type of scroll view depending on portrait or landscape mode, that you provide different ids for each and then handle this in code by checking for the presence of the view in the layout first, and if it's there, you know which one you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Just some further findings based on Michael's answer.

So when I have different layouts for portrait and landscape, all named views must be same type in portrait and landscape layouts, otherwise it crashes when user rotates screen. This is not necessary for unnamed views.

For my problem, I created both HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView and add suffix _hsv and _sv to id. For portrait _sv is not used so set visibility to Gone, for landscape set _hsv visibility to Gone.

In code, I check which one is in use by checking visibility == View.Gone or not. This fixes all my problem.

Thanks Michael and all!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you with out seeing the RUN log, and the code, could you copy both into your into your question?

Sorry not enough rep to comment.